# How to properly use NSCache?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem when I want to save strings (or anything else) with NSCache, although I saw a lot of tutorials and copy-pasted codes.

Right now what I last tried is cache a simple string and then retrieving it, just for testing.

```swift
let cache = NSCache<NSString, NSString>()
if let cachedObject = cache.object(forKey: "test" as NSString) {
    print("Cached \(cachedObject)")
} else {
    let test = "Testing"
    cache.setObject(test as NSString, forKey: "test" as NSString)
    print("Not cached \(test)")
}
```

When I see the log output, it prints always "Not cached Testing". Just like if it never cached anything. I don't know how can I fix this, it got on my nerves for a couple of days.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, in the code you posted, you never cache before asking for the value. So the code behaves as expected.

Comment: Yes I know, the first time I load the view, it prints "Not cached Testing" but also caches that string. But when I load twice the view it prints the same thing again

Comment: Then please provide some minimal code that we can use to reproduce your problem.

Comment: `NSCache` is an in-memory cache. Items in the cache do not persist between seperate executions of your app. You need to test by inserting and retrieving from a cache instance in the one execution.

Comment: Voting to reopen this because it's definitely not off-topic. There's a minimal, reproducible example, and the desired behavior is clear. The OP is simply confused about NSCache's expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> When I see the log output, it prints always "Not cached Testing". Just like if it never cached anything. I don't know how can I fix this, it got on my nerves for a couple of days.

Run that same code inside a loop. The first time through, you'll get the *Not cached* message because the object hasn't been added to the cache yet. On each subsequent time through the loop, you'll get *Cached* because the object will have been added to the cache.

> What I think my problem is, it's that when I re-build the app, the cache clears itself. However when I restart the app it said again "Not cached" on the first line.

Yes, that's the expected behavior. Paulw11 correctly pointed out in a comment above that NSCache is not persistent. That is, the objects in the cache aren't written to disk; the cache and its contents exist only in memory. The [NSCache reference page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscache) says:

*A mutable collection you use to temporarily store transient key-value pairs that are subject to eviction when resources are low.*

Think of NSCache as a dictionary that you can use to store large objects (like images) without worrying about using too much memory. Let's say you're writing a photo album, and you'd like to avoid re-reading photos from disk every single time you need one, but at the same time you can't have *all* the photos in memory at once because that would use way too much memory. So instead, you create an instance of NSCache for the photos. Before you read a photo from disk, you can try to get it from the cache. If it's not there, then you read it in from disk and add it to the cache. On the other hand, if the object *is* in the cache, then you get it without having to read it again, and that makes your app perform better.

Don't use NSCache to store data that you can't re-create some other way (e.g. re-read it from disk or recompute it). And know that when the app exits, the cache will go away along with all the other objects in memory.

Comment: Hey! Well, I tried what you said and you're right. The first print said "Not cached" but in the following ones it said "Cached". What I think my problem is, it's that when I re-build the app, the cache clears itself. However when I restart the app it said again "Not cached" on the first line.

Comment: @NicolásVillar That's exactly the expected behavior. As PaulW11 pointed out in a comment, NSCache is not persistent. Read [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscache?language=objc). An instance of NSCache exists in memory like any other object, which means that when the app exits the cache goes away. Not only that, but if memory gets low, the cache will start releasing the objects it contains. That's the point, actually: you can use it to store large objects (like images) in memory without worrying that you're using too much memory; it'll dump objects if needed.